# codeSign Error: cannot allow to use key "" in my keychain

Tags: ios, xcode, codesign

When I choose my iPhone to run my Xcode project, it ask me if I want to sign using key "" in your keychain,and when I clicked "Allow", the window doesn't disappear, but click "Deny" button, it disappeared....

[image]

What can I do please?

Comment: Always Allow btn did'n make the dialog window disappear neither

Comment: Are you on El Capitan? It's a known bug, and unfortunately there is no known fix besides completely removing the keychain and starting over. We've been plagued with this bug as well.

Comment: Yes,My OS X version is EI Capitan.And When I delete my keys and Certificates in Keychai,and reinstall,it worked fine,and i could use iPhone to debug my app.